# Local System Account in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

Have the security persmission or anything else changed for the Local System Account in Windows Server 2008 versus Windows Server 2003?  We have a service, that logs on as the Local System Account, that creates folders on the server (same server as the service is installed).  It works perfectly when installed on Windows Server 2003 however when installed in Windows Server 2008 the folders do not get created.  It appears as if the Local System Account does not have persmission to create the folders.  Any insight that anyone can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought would be User Account Control

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control

Depending on the use of the machine, it may be worthwhile turning it off and in other cases not so much. It's a bit of a controversial subject :)

Try disabling this through the Control Panel -> users and see if this helps :)

Comment: +1, This is correct; by default processes do not run elevated, which it would need to create folders on the drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your system account to the local machine's administrators group and it's not set by default in Windows 2008.